# Calculator should accepting all operators

Tags: jquery

Can u please help on this on this calculator.

[image][image]

Comment: Add relevant Code in OP not just an image

Comment: you can edit your question instead of posting it in Answer area.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idCalculadoratxtResultado").focus();
    $(function () {
    $("input[id*='idCalculadoratxtResultado']").keyup(function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (isNaN(val)) {
            debugger;
            val = val.replace("^[0-9+-*\\-`.+,/\"]*$", '');
            if (val.split('..').length > 1)
                val = val.replace(/\.+$/, ".");                
            if (val.split('++').length > 1)
                val = val.replace('++', "+");
            if (val.split('--').length > 1)
                val = val.replace('--', "-");
            if (val.split('**').length > 1)
                val = val.replace('**', "*");
            if (val.split('//').length > 1)
                val = val.replace('//', "/");             
        }
        $(this).val(val);
    });
    });
    $("#idCalculadora").on("keydown", function search(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(".btn-warning").focus();
        }
    });
    $("#idCalculadora").Calculadora();
});   
$("#idCalculadora").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Calculator",
    overflow: "hidden",
    width: "300",
    //close: function () {
    //    $('#idCalculadora').empty();
    //}
});
$('#Calculator').click(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#idCalculadora").removeClass('hide');
    $("#idCalculadora").dialog("open");
});
```

here I am using this  code and plugins only and not any code for this

Answer (score 0):

The output is not coming for this. the text box can accept any operator continuously and should accept all operators at the time.
SimpleCalculadorajQuery.css
SimpleCalculadorajQuery.js